# KeyPress malfunction in Opera

Tags: javascript, browser, keypress, opera, dom-events

I'm using the following code to detect users' key pressing, in JavaScript:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
    'use strict';
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;

        switch (keyCode) {
        case '{N}':
             doSomething();
             break;

        default:
             break;
        }
});
```

Where `doSomething` is a previously defined function and `{N}` is any of the [JavaScript Char Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

It works properly in every major browser, but in [Opera](http://www.opera.com/) even if a key remains pressed, it only calls `doSomething` once, instead of doing it **until** the key is released.
What can I do to fix this?

---

### Edit

I solved it using the `keypress` event instead of `keydown` (which is not well handled by Opera).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a known bug which should (finally!) get fixed soon. In short, keydown events are not repeated while keypress events are. Listening to keypress instead if you want repetition (and don't care about keys that do NOT fire keypress in all browsers like most function keys) should be a reasonable cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

Opera makes a mess, the keydown event does not repeat, and you cannot prevent the default for keydown in opera. For more http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/