# Opera / Chrome does not detect keypress

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keypress

I am working on a javascript application where I need to detect keypress, keyup and keydown events.

Here is my code:

```
    document.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPress);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyDown);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyUp);
```

The listener for keyup and keydown gets called in Opera, Firefox and Chrome. But the listener for **keypress** does not get called in Opera and Chrome. It gets called only in Firefox.

Why keypress is not being handled?

**Browser versions:** 
Opera: 12.15 
Firefox: 23.0 
Chrome: 28.0.1500.95

Comment: I dont know why keypress is not being handled

Comment: Did you try to use Google before asking? Well, if you search "keypress event chrome", the first result gives you this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311290/keypress-event-not-working-in-ie-and-chrome-but-working-in-ff

Comment: I did google but I couldnt find a solution that fits all browsers. And I am having exact oppsite results (keypress works there, but not in mine) to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200589/keypress-malfunction-in-opera so I am really confused.

Comment: keypress is not a standard event for all browsers. use keydown.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Comment: @iGanja Thanks a lot! I have not thought along those lines.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the third required parameter for addEventListener (use false).

Also try adding the listener to 'window' instead.

Comment: I tried both, but same result. Actually keydown and keyup works so third param / window is not the issue. But as iGanja commented on my post I used keydown instead of keypress and it worked.

Comment: I may have misread the question. Sorry. Glad you got it working!